# [rospack] couldn't find package [rviz]

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After following the install instructions here http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect rviz has disappeared! It worked before.

:~$ rosrun rviz rviz

[rospack] couldn't find package [rviz]

:~$ roscd rviz

roscd: No such package 'rviz'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9923/%5Brospack%5D-couldn%27t-find-package-%5Brviz%5D/) by [manos](https://answers.ros.org/users/503/manos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is missing the stacks directory. It should read something like:
"other stuff":/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please provide more details about what instructions you followed, e.g. apt-get vs. source install.  Please also provide information on your environment variables, like ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support for examples of information that are useful.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2